# bash shell: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm following instructions on a implementing a script that seemed clear to me, upon running it I'm told there is an error with line 36. Can't seem to understand the problem.

```
line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
line 36: `  else'
```

The code:

```
   if [ "$answer" = "y" ] #Backup all VMs if answer is yes
  then
          for num in 1 2 3 #Determiant loop for 3 arguments: 1, 2, and 3
  do
          echo "Backing up VM #$num"
          gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos$num.qcow2 > /root/centos$num.qcow2.backup.gz
          echo "VM #$num BACKUP DONE"
  done

  elif [ "$answer = "n" ]
  then
          read -p "Which VM should be backed up? '(1/2/3)': " numanswer
   until echo "$numanswer" | grep "^[123]$" >> /dev/null # Look for match of single digit: 1, 2, or 3
  do
           read -p "Invalid Selection. Select 1,2, or 3: " numanswer
          echo "Backing up VM #$numanswer"
  gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos$numanswer.qcow2 > /root/centos$numanswer.qcow2.backup.gz
          echo "VM #$numanswer BACKUP DONE":
          else ### line 36 
          echo "Invalid Selection... Aborting program"

  exit2
  fi
```

Comment: it would be nice to have an initial `if` test in your sample code AND an `until` loop requires a closing `done`. Probably other things need fixing too. Paste your complete code into http://shellcheck.net (including `#!/bin/bash` or whatever for the first line). Good luck.

Comment: I added the initial if statement for it, i'll give that site a try. thanks.

Comment: You forgot the closing quote around `$answer` on line 27.

Comment: Consider, in the future, running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: (Also, for the future -- generally, we ask you to build a [mcve] for questions with code: something that's the *shortest possible program* that generates the same error).

Answer (score 1):

The script should read:

```
 27 elif [ "$answer = "n" ]
 28 then
 29     read -p "Which VM should be backed up? '(1/2/3)': " numanswer
 30     until echo "$numanswer" | grep "^[123]$" >> /dev/null # Look for match of single digit: 1, 2, or 3
 31     do
 32         read -p "Invalid Selection. Select 1,2, or 3: " numanswer
 33     done
 34     echo "Backing up VM #$numanswer"
 35     gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos$numanswer.qcow2 > /root/centos$numanswer.qcow2.backup.gz
 36     echo "VM #$numanswer BACKUP DONE":
 37 else
 38     echo "Invalid Selection... Aborting program"
 39     exit2
 40 fi
```

Note the `done` in 33, this was needed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work nicely:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do
        read -r -p $'Which VM should be backed up? [1, 2, 3, or All]\n\n\tPlease enter your selection: ' numanswer
        case "$numanswer" in
            1)
                echo "Backing up VM #1"
                gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos1.qcow2 > /root/centos1.qcow2.backup.gz
                echo "VM #1 BACKUP DONE"
                break
                ;;
            2)
                echo "Backing up VM #2"
                gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos2.qcow2 > /root/centos2.qcow2.backup.gz
                echo "VM #2 BACKUP DONE"
                break
                ;;
            3)
                echo "Backing up VM #3"
                gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos3.qcow2 > /root/centos3.qcow2.backup.gz
                echo "VM #3 BACKUP DONE"
                break
                ;;
            All)
                for num in 1 2 3
                    do
                        echo "Backing up VM #$num"
                        gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos$num.qcow2 > /root/centos$num.qcow2.backup.gz
                        echo "VM #$num BACKUP DONE"
                    done
                break
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Invalid input"
                continue
                ;;
        esac
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `until` statement but no  `done` to close the loop. So the `else` is getting lost in their.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the trailing colon on line 35

Comment: No dice mate, still getting the same error.

Comment: nope, a colon is either a no-op char, or in this case it is just concatenated with the string that is being `echo`ed.

Comment: as already reported in a comment, the issue is a missing `"` at line 27